# iOS Auto Layout Problems

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I am new to auto layout and am experiencing some problems. Take the following portrait view:
[image: Portrait View]

I'd like to be able to rotate the device and get a view that looks like this:

[image: Landscape view]

The button and label have fixed heights, and so I'd like the image view and the table view to resize. I can't figure out how to achieve this using auto layout. Is it even achievable at all?

I've been able to do something similar, but with a fixed height for the image view, but this is something I don't want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your description it looks like it resize, you mean that the content view of your table stay at previous width for example ?

Comment: No, the widths are fine, but without specifying a height for the image view, I get all sorts of strange conflicts.

Comment: What is the relation between heights of UIImageView and UITableView?

Comment: You can set up an auto layout relation for scale ratio of your UIImageView, so it always keep square if it square for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with AutoLayout.

UIImage View:

- Top Space to: Superview = 0
- Trailing Space to: Superview = 0
- Leading Space to: Superview = 0
- Bottom Space to: UIButton = 0
- Height greater than or equal to: (some minimum size)

UIButton:

- Top Space to: ImageView = 0
- Trailing Space to: Superview = 0
- Leading Space to: Superview = 0
- Bottom Space to: UILabel = 0
- Height equal to: (some height)

UILabel:

- Top Space to: UIButton = 0
- Trailing Space to: Superview = 0
- Leading Space to: Superview = 0
- Bottom Space to: UITableView = 0
- Height equal to: (some height)

UITableView:

- Top Space to: UILabel = 0
- Trailing Space to: Superview = 0
- Leading Space to: Superview = 0
- Bottom Space to: Superview = 0
- Height greater than or equal to: (some minimum size)

Comment: The errors thrown by autoLayout can be very helpful, even if they are cryptic at first. Clicking the little red or yellow arrow in the editor on your left takes you to them. They should all go away once you've created all these constraints. You may also find it easier to layout the top and bottom elements first, then string up the middle two. Keep fiddling till it works, and you will have pure magic in every orientation on every device size.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do it simply in in IB. In my opinion you got two options:

1. Do everything programmatically using VLF, adding constraints and removing them using the rotation methods of UIViewController
2. Add all your constraint in IB giving portrait constraints the maximum priority and landscape constraints the lowest. Right before rotation according to the orientation you can change the priority, from lower to higher and viceversa

You can do something as you want if you give UIImageView and UItableView the same height as constraint.